# How to get For which Begin there is no End

Tags: regex, perl

Hello i have a huge file which has 1000s of BEGIN and END,i am looking for a logic which will tell me for each BEGIN there is END or not.

for ex:

```
    # Begin Variable

      Name = loopEndDriven
      Decl_type = UInt8
      Usage = Z
      Value = CE_SELECT

    # End Variable

    # Begin Variable

      Name = locationNeeded
      Decl_type = Loop_Location_t
      Usage = Z
      Value = SHORT_LOCATION

    # End Variable
```

Comment: Can they be nested? Or does each begin need to be followed by an end?

Comment: count the begin and end both must be same in number

Comment: `"i am looking for a logic which will tell me for each BEGIN there is END or not."` - what have you tried?

Comment: But how do i 'll know which line or for which BEGIN there is no END.I am confued in this part.any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You first say that you are looking for `BEGIN` and `END`, then in the sample input, you say it is `#Begin Variable`. It's not a very smart idea to ask for help with matching a string, and then not saying what the string looks like. You should say *exactly* what the string looks like, and show examples that show *exactly* how it might look. Not approximatively, not "Variable" if it says "Foo". Exactly.

Comment: @Zaid i tried like copy entire string between BEGIN and END and Search if there is any BEGIN in between.Its not so feasible idea.

Comment: @TLP # Begin Variable and  # End Variable is common through out the file..I just want the logic how may i proceed to check for which # Begin Variable there is no # End Variable.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. So the string is exactly `# Begin Variable` and `# End Variable`. Nothing else? It is always exactly the same?

Comment: YES strings are exactly # Begin Variable and # End Variable and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN{$t=0}
           if(/Begin/ ||(eof && $t==1))
           {print "No end at $." unless($t==0);$t=1}
           $t=0 if(/End/);' your_file
```

This above command will print the line number when there is no End for each Begin.
I have tested below:

```
> cat temp
    # Begin Variable

      Name = loopEndDriven
      Decl_type = UInt8
      Usage = Z
      Value = CE_SELECT

    # End Variable

    # Begin Variable

      Name = locationNeeded
      Decl_type = Loop_Location_t
      Usage = Z
      Value = SHORT_LOCATION

    # Begin Variable

      Name = locationNeeded
      Decl_type = Loop_Location_t
      Usage = Z
      Value = SHORT_LOCATION

> perl -lne 'BEGIN{$t=0}if(/Begin/ ||(eof && $t==1)){print "No end at $." unless($t==0);$t=1}$t=0 if(/End/);' temp
No end at 17
No end at 23
>
```

On the similar lines i hope you can also write the logic to check for each End there is a Begin or not.

Comment: Fails to detect an `End` on the last line. (Failing test: `Begin<LF>foo<LF>End<LF>`)

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to give an error for `Begin<LF>End<LF>End<LF>` too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming nesting isn't allowed.

```
my $in_begin = 0;
while (<>) {
   if (/# Begin/) {
      warn(qq{Missing "End" at line $.\n"}) if $in_begin;
      $in_begin = 1;
   }
   elsif (/# End/) {
      warn(qq{Missing "Begin" at line $.\n"}) if !$in_begin;
      $in_begin = 0;
   }
}

warn(qq{Missing "End" at EOF\n"}) if $in_begin;
```

---

Better diagnostics:

```
my $begin = 0;
while (<>) {
   if (/# Begin/) {
      warn(qq{Missing "End" for "Begin" at line $begin\n}) if $begin;
      $begin = $.;
   }
   elsif (/# End/) {
      warn(qq{Missing "Begin" for "End' at line $.\n"}) if !$begin;
      $begin = 0;
   }
}

warn(qq{Missing "End" for "Begin" at line $begin\n"}) if $begin;
```

Comment: Oops, a check was missing. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

### Balanced Expressions

There are no BEGIN or END keywords in the corpus you posted. The following one-liner will check for balanced expressions using your block comments instead.

```
$ perl -ne '$pairs += 1 if /Begin Variable/;
            $pairs -= 1 if /End Variable/;
            END {
              if ($pairs == 0) {print "balanced\n"} else {print "unbalanced\n"}
            }' /tmp/foo
```

With your corpus as currently posted, the one-liner should print `balanced`.

Comment: Won't END ... BEGIN will also print balanced with this expression?

Comment: But how do i 'll know which line or for which BEGIN there is no END.I am confued in this part.

Comment: @JayElston It's not a syntax checker; it's just looking for balanced pairs.

Answer (score 0):

As you ask for logic rather than implementation:

- Walk through the file line by line
- Increment a variable each time you encounter `# Begin Variable`
- Decrement this variable each time you encounter `# End Variable`
- If the variable ever becomes `2`, the previous block was unended. Record this somehow and decrement.